# SAX Parser doesn't recognize windows-1255 encoding

Tags: java, android, encoding, rss, sax

I'm working on a rss parser in android
 (upgrading a parser I found on the internet).
From what I know SAX Parser recognize the encoding automatically from the xml tag, but when I try to parse a feed that declare windows-1255 encoding it doesn't parsing it and throws and exception.
I tried few things:

1. ```
   final InputSource source = new InputSource(feed);
   Reader isr = new InputStreamReader(feed);
   source.setCharacterStream(isr);
   ```
2. I even tried telling him the specific encoding.

   ```
   source.setEncoding("Windows-1255");
   ```
3. Tried to look at the locator:

   ```
   @Override
   public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
   }
   ```

And it recognize the encoding as UTF-16.

Please help me solve this annoying problem!
Sorry for the mess with code snippets the code button refuse to work for some reason.

Comment: `rss` is an `xml`. Is encoding declared at the beginning of the document? I mean `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255" ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the platform itself doesn't know about the "windows-1255" encoding. After all, it's a Windows-based encoding - I wouldn't want to *rely* on it being available on any other platforms, particularly mobile ones where things are generally cut down to the "must-have" options.

Comment: I tried to check what you said so I took the stream and encoded it to a string by myself:  
     `byte[] arr = new byte[4096];  
     int bytesNum = feedStream.read(arr, 0, 4096);  
     while (bytesNum > 0){  
      String s = new String(arr, 0, bytesNum, "windows-1255");  
      Log.i("", s);  
      System.out.println(s);  
      bytesNum = feedStream.read(arr, 0, 4096);  
     }  
     
     return null;  `


And string looks just fine (the code ran on the android device so it means that it does support windows-1255 encoding).

Comment: @Elad92: Interesting - and surprising. In that case, you *could* read the whole thing into memory, convert it to UTF-8, rewrite the XML declaration part, and then get SAX to parse it at that point. Not terribly pleasant, but it should work...

Comment: I tried to avoid reading all the stream into the memory, because this parsing must bee as light as possible because Android devices doesn't have computer like processing abilities. If this code wasn't suppose to run on Android I would have used DOM parser instead of SAX.. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Elad92: Hmm... you could *try* writing an "in-stream encoding converter" which converts the bytes from windows-1255 to UTF-8 on the fly *and* converts the declaration. That's likely to be nasty to implement though :(

Comment: @JonSkeet chars in UTF-8 takes more bytes, than in windows-1255. In-place convertion hardly will work.

Comment: @kirilloid: It's a stream - you don't have to read from the original stream into the same byte array that the caller passes in. You can *absolutely* do this in-place, in the same way that it would be possible to write an `InputStream` to proxy another one, repeating every byte (so 1 2 3 4 5 became 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5). It's the same principle, just more awkward. The fiddly bit is stripping the windows-1255 from the XML declaration...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the encoding to the InputStreamReader.

```
Reader isr = new InputStreamReader(feed, "windows-1255");
final InputSource source = new InputSource(isr);
```

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) the logic for reading from InputSource goes something like this:

- Is there a character stream? if there is, use that(This is what happens if you use a Reader like InputStreamReader)

Otherwise:

- No character stream? Use byte stream. (InputStream)
- Is there a encoding set for InputSource? Use that
- There was no encoding set? Try parsing the encoding from the xml file

Comment: I did it and it worked, but I can't do it hardcoded because the feeds are in different encodings.. how can I force him to parse the encoding from xml?

Comment: If you want to parse encoding from xml, just use new InputSource(feed), no need for a Reader. Of course in that case your xml file will need to start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255" ?>

Comment: That's what I did in the first place, but it refuse to works, and when it reach the first charcter it throws an unknown encoding exception.