# How to get XML declaration header? Android

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a rss reader app for android and now i need to know what is the encoding of xml before i start parsing it (windows-1251 or utf-8). This is described in xml declaration header i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. How can i get this header before parsing? I use android.sax implementation of sax parser and pass encoding as string parameter to InputStreamReader.
   I found a related question:
[SAX Parser doesn't recognize windows-1255 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931024/sax-parser-doesnt-recognize-windows-1255-encoding) - but the solution there is to convert cp-1251 to utf-8, which is too cumbersome and demanding on resources. I think there must be better solution, as i only need to know encoding value from header `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. But i can't manage to get this header from xml, parser starts from `<rss>` tag. How should i get it?

Comment: **"How can i get this header before parsing?"** - Open the XML file as a text file and read the first line and check for "encoding="UTF-8"" perhaps? Just a thought.

Comment: This is obvious and correct answer to problem. For some reason i searched for something more complex :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to Android's officially supported [xmlPullParser](http://www.xmlpull.org/) and the encoding support issue should go away.

Here is the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) on it.

Do not think lightly of this as the SAX parser does not work well in Android v3.0+

Comment: Thanks, maybe i'll switch to it later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question was pretty obvious :) Here is the code that worked, based on Squonk's comment:

```
byte[] data = new byte[50];     
            try{
            bs.mark(60);
            bs.read(data, 0, data.length);
            String value = new String(data,"UTF-8");
            if(value.toLowerCase().contains("utf-8"))
                return "UTF-8";
            else if(value.contains("1251"))
                return "windows-1251";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("debug", "Exception: " + e);
                return "XML not found";
            }
```

Then just reset bs (BufferedInputStream) and work with it in any needed charset.