# how to read encoding attribute of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nsxmlparser, saxparser

can anybody help me to get encoding attribute value from `<?xml` tag in xml which program receives as `ByteArrayInputStream`.

I have tried using `inputSource.getencoding()` but it gives encoding of system not of file

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922764/how-to-get-xml-declaration-header-android

Answer (score -1):

Get it via getEncoding() on the parsed Document.

Comment: what should be the way to get using parsed Doc , can u explore a bit using code example.